# How do you tag EC2 instances spawned by ECS in Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs

I have an ECS service that spawns some containers:

```
resource "aws_ecs_service" "rocketchat" {
  name            = "rocketchat-ecs-service"
  cluster         = "${aws_ecs_cluster.rocketchat.id}"
  task_definition = "${aws_ecs_task_definition.rocketchat.arn}"
  desired_count   = 2
  iam_role        = "${aws_iam_role.ecs_service.name}"
...
```

But the EC2 instances it creates have no 'Name' tag. I thought that `name_prefix` was what I was looking for, but it doesn't work:

```
resource "aws_launch_configuration" "rocketchat" {
  security_groups             = ["${aws_security_group.instance_sg.id}"]
  name_prefix                 = "${var.project_prefix}-rocketchat-"
  key_name                    = "${aws_key_pair.circles_rocketchat.key_name}"
...
```

The task definition for this container also has a name field, which doesn't work either:

```
[
  {
    "name": "rocketchat",
    "cpu": 256,
    "essential": true,
...
```

[Amazon docs say here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Using_Tags.html#tag-resources) that 'tagging on creation' is not supported 'Launch template' but I am not sure that is exactly relevant; esp when you take my other ECS service on the same cluster, which doesn't have a load balancer, and therefore has no launch configuration.

EDIT:

@B.Miller s suggestion below has not tagged the actual instances but it does show in the console under EC2 > Auto Scaling Groups > Tags

`+-------------+---------------------+-------------------+
| Key         | Value               | Tag New Instances |
+-------------+---------------------+-------------------+
| Environment | dev                 | Yes               |
+-------------+---------------------+-------------------+
| Name        | rocketchat-instance | Yes               |
+-------------+---------------------+-------------------+`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`name_prefix` creates a randomly unique name for the launch configuration using the prefix, not prefixs the things launched with it. `name` in a task definition is the name of the task definition itself. Because you are using a launch configuration I assume you are using an [autoscaling group](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/autoscaling_group.html). Autoscaling groups allow you to set [tags](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/autoscaling_group.html#tags) then [propagate those tags](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/autoscaling_group.html#propagate_at_launch).

For example you can [specify individual tags and have them propogate](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/autoscaling_group.html#interpolated-tags):

> ```
> resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "default" {
>   ...
>   tags = [
>     {
>       key                 = "explicit1"
>       value               = "value1"
>       propagate_at_launch = true
>     },
>     {
>       key                 = "explicit2"
>       value               = "value2"
>       propagate_at_launch = true
>     },
>   ]
>   ...
> }
> ```

Edit: **note that this works with the ECS-Optimised Amazon AMI but not CoreOS.**

Comment: That didn't work for me; no errors in terraform but the instances are still not tagged.

Comment: Console actually shows the tags are set to propagate as well? @edzillion

Comment: It does, but I am having some weird issue now with my ASG. It's being ingored. Maybe that's the underlying problem

Comment: actually I think it might just be an issue with the aws console. I can see my ASG in one view but it states I don't have one when I view the cluster. Still no Name tags though.

Comment: Odd, you'd think Terraform would throw an error if it didn't exist. In any case, this is how the tagging works. Not sure why it's not working though.

Comment: hey @b.miller I realised it wasn't working because I was using CoreOS and this feature requires the Amazon ECS-optimised AMI. I have edited your answer just to point that out, and accepted it. I hope you don't mind!